# How to suppress the hanging-over text part of a section title within the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

My question is, if there exists a method to suppress hanging-over text elements in the table of contents. Below you will find my MWE. Thanks a lot for your solutions and comments!

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{FlushLeft}
\tableofcontents
\end{FlushLeft}
\chapter{chapter -- what a very long  acronym (\emph{qwertzuiopasdfghjk})}
some text
\section{section -- what a very long and even longer heading with this acronym \emph{qwertzuiopasdfghjk}}
some text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{10}
\section{Another section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you want the long line to be truncated, or wrapped to a second line?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear but perhaps you want `\chapter[short version]{chapter -- what a very long  acronym (\emph{qwertzuiopasdfghjk})}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton I want the long line to be wrapped to a second line.

Comment: As far as I know, too long lines in titles of chapter, sections, &c., are automatically wrapped. I don't really understand what you require.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I want the long line to be wrapped to a second line without hyphenation.

Comment: @Bernard -- if hyphenation is suppressed, the first line will either become overfull or stretched beyond what looks good.  the best solution is to set the contents entry ragged right (keeping the page number fixed at the right margin).  i know how to do this for some (the ams) document classes, but not for `scrbook`, and i don't use title- or contents-adjusting packages.  if no one else comes up with a solution first, i will experiment tomorrow to achieve an attractive result.

Comment: @ Barbara Beeton – I didn't take into account the fact that was the scrbook class, which I do not use myself. However I had no problem to do so using titletoc, and I've heard komascript is compatible with titlesec…

Comment: @barbarabeeton Did you get a solution for my problem? Or do you need more details?

Answer (score 2):

Using package `tocstyle`, you can set the entries in the toc ragged right.

[image: friedrichKomaTocRaggedright]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
\settocfeature{raggedhook}{\raggedright}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{3em}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter -- what a very long  acronym
    (\emph{qwertzuiopasdfghjk})
}
some text
\section{section -- what a very long and even longer
    heading with this acronym
    \emph{qwertzuiopasdfghjk}
}
some text\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1000}
\section{Well, this is quite the text and nobody
    should ever use section or chapter titles that
    long. However, we want to see if that is raggedright or
not. Justified text would look different.}
\end{document}
```